# Slider Control in Android

Tags: android, widget, slider

How can i implement slider control (without using seek bar) in android?

Like, [AT&T Slider Control](http://developer.att.com/developer/forward.jsp?passedItemId=5300044)

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1):

Straight-forward decision: use 2 ImageView (slider and bar) and move one along other.

Or try to override SeekBar, override method onTouch() and return in it true.